# Transform promise/ajax into a synchronous request

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

I have the following situation:

I have some code that runs on a local server (only needs to support Chrome). This code currently runs asynchronous as it is from a tutorial. However for my use-case it would be much easier for me to have the code run synchronously.

```
function creosonConnect() {

    // JSON request
    var reqObj =  {
        "command": "connection",
        "function": "connect"
    };

    // perform the request
    creosonRequest(reqObj)
        .then(function(respObj) {

            console.log('got this back: '+JSON.stringify(respObj));
            console.log('SESSIONID ===> '+respObj.sessionId);
            creosonSessionId = respObj.sessionId;
        });
}

function creosonRequest (dataObj) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        creosonServerSettingsObj.data = JSON.stringify(dataObj);

        $.ajax(
            creosonServerSettingsObj
        )
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log('got to the success : '+JSON.stringify(data))
                console.log('got this data type back: '+typeof data);

                if (data.status.error) {
                    if (data.status.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
                        reject(data.status.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        reject('creoson Operation failed! - check console for details');
                    }
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            })
            .error( function (e) {
                console.log('got an error : '+JSON.stringify(e));
                reject('creoson Operation failed! - check console for details');
            });
    })
}
```

My problem is that I have zero experience working with servers/web development in general. If I try to chain several functions that depend on the first one (creosonConnect) being completed, it all collapses around me.
Ideally I'd want to do something like this:

```
function main(){

    creosonConnect();
    creoOpenModel();
    ...
}

function creoOpenModel (partName) {

    // JSON request
    var reqObj =  {
        "sessionId": creosonSessionId,
        "command": "file",
        "function": "open",
        "data": {
            "file": null,
            "display": true,
            "activate": true
        }
    };

    // get the input value & set to the reqObj
    var fileName = partName
    reqObj.data.file = fileName;

    // perform the request
    creosonRequest(reqObj)
        .then(function(respObj) {

            console.log('got this back: ' + JSON.stringify(respObj));
        });
}
```

Any help how to transform this into synchronous code is greatly appreciated. Also some explanation what exactly is going on in the creosonRequest function would be fantastic.

I know this is a lot to ask but I am really at a loss here. Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: You can use async await functions

Comment: "Transform promise/ajax into a synchronous request" — You can't do that.

Comment: @Max I have already stumbled upon this concept, but unfortunately I am not sure how I can implement this in my specific case. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Quentin but surely there has to be a way to perform a function, wait for the response from the server and then continue with the next function? I don't mind if this requires something different than ajax/promise.

Comment: @frage12358 — That's what the `then` method of the promise object is for.

Comment: @Quentin there are a lot of documentations about it. One article I've read recently is https://css-tricks.com/understanding-async-await/

Comment: @Quentin I think I understand what you mean, but wouldn't that result in one big, incredibly nested function. If I have, let's say 6 functions that all should be executed one after the other, wouldn't that with the then construct be super messy and hard to follow?

Comment: @frage12358 — No. https://jsbin.com/dinuyoyogi/1/edit?html,js,console,output (edit: fix link)

Answer (score -1):

You could try to do something with async/await and wait for your connect function to finish.

Have you tried something like:

```
async function main(){

   await creosonConnect();
   creoOpenModel();
   ...
}
```